# How to use Existing .so file in android application

Tags: android, pdf, java-native-interface, pdftron, pdfnet

I was searching for library which should convert .doc/.docx to .pdf in android platform.

I got PdFTron android sdk,in that they have given libPDFNetC.so file.

For Conversion, there is class called Convert, inside that there is a method toPDF(),
in that method they have internally called native method FileToPdf().I tried that code but unable to call that native method and was getting errors

I want to know that if there is  existing .so file present with you and if you want to call native method which is present in .so file then is there need to use JNI?. i dont know much about JNI. any help.

Answer (score 4):

You have to link your final shared library that is generated by the Android NDK using the `ndk-build` to the PDF shared library you said ***you already have compiled for the ARM architecture***. 
(**Ensure that this is the case, otherwise the library won't work on Android!**)

For that, if for example you have the following directory structure:

```
jni
└── libs
└────── my_shared_lib.so
└── Android.mk
└── Application.mk
```

You need to have the following content inside the **Android.mk** file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# define our prebuilt shared library as a module to the build system
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := mysharedlib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/my_shared_lib.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# The final shared library that will be bundled inside the .apk
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := mynativelib
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -landroid -llog
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -O0 -g3 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra 
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := mysharedlib
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := myheader1.h myheader2.h
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := src_file1.cpp src_file2.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and the contents of the **Application.mk** file (for using the C++ Standard Library, and  build the the final shared library for two different versions of the ARM architecture):

```
APP_OPTIM := debug
APP_PLATFORM := android-14
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
```

Then after you compile your code from within Eclipse or from the command line using the **ndk-build** script it'll compile you final shared library and link it against your prebuilt shared library (i.e. the PDF shared library you said you are trying to use).

**For shared libraries the apk that is generated and deployed to the device/emulator contains the final shared library as well as all the prebuilt shared libraries you linked against**, in contrast with linking against static libraries which are not bundled inside the apk.

For your use case you should have two shared libraries in the lib directory of your Android application after the apk is unpacked on the device.
You can check this by running the following command from a terminal:

```
adb shell ls -l /data/data/com.company.myapp/lib
```

Replace com.company.myapp with your application's package name.

Also, don't forget to put the following inside a static context of a Java class:

```
class MyClass
{
      static
      {
            try
            {
                System.loadLibrary("mynativelib");
            }
            catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError ule)
            {
               Log.e(TAG, "WARNING: Could not load native library: " 
                      + ule.getMessage());
            }
      }

       // other code here...
}
```

Notice the use of the **same** name inside the System.loadLibrary method call as the final shared library name.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the .so file that maps to the native interface is available on your system, and can be found by Java.

There should be a call like `System.loadLibrary("<libraryname>")` or `System.load("/path/to/libs/lib<libraryname>.so")` somewhere in your Java code.
That will instruct the JVM to search for the library with the given name and load it.

- `System.load("/path/to/libs/lib<libraryname>.so")` will just look for the file specified as argument, and load it.
- `System.loadLibrary("<libraryname.")` will look in the configured library path for a library  with the name `lib<libraryname>.so` . The library path is taken from the system variable `java.library.path` .

Also make sure that the library version you are loading is compatible with the Java JNI mapping!

Comment: Thanks for Reply, i already tried system.load("data/data/package-name/libfile.so") method. but i am getting same error .01-18 15:34:30.875: E/AndroidRuntime(26106): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 15:34:30.875: E/AndroidRuntime(26106): java.lang.RuntimeException: re-throw on exception class missing constructor
01-18 15:34:30.875: E/AndroidRuntime(26106):  at pdftron.PDF.Convert.FileToPdf(Native Method)
01-18 15:34:30.875: E/AndroidRuntime(26106):  at pdftron.PDF.Convert.toPdf(SourceFile:642)
01-18 15:34:30.875: E/AndroidRuntime(26106):  at

Comment: That error is cut off...
Can you post the error between code tags so we can see what is going wrong?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(16963): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(16963): java.lang.RuntimeException: re-throw on exception class missing constructor
E/AndroidRuntime(16963):at pdftron.PDF.Convert.FileToPdf(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16963):at pdftron.PDF.Convert.toPdf(SourceFile:642)
E/AndroidRuntime(16963):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16963): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(16963):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(16963): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(16963): java.lang.RuntimeException: re-throw on exception class missing constructor
 E/AndroidRuntime(16963):at pdftron.PDF.Convert.FileToPdf(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16963):at pdftron.PDF.Convert.toPdf(SourceFile:642)
E/AndroidRuntime(16963):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16963): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(16963):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
E/AndroidRuntime(16963):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
E/AndroidRuntime(16963): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: In the code i called the method toPDF() of class Convert which is present in PDFNet.jar file, from that class(method) they are internally calling native method fileToPDF(), while accessing that method i am getting above errors also i added jar in build path so no problem of that,only problem of .so file access.. @Dieter Van de Walle ... thanks

Comment: Please put the exception log on pastebin.com or something, I really can't read this / understand.

Answer (score 0):

To work on ndk , there is a .mk (make file) that is complied under JNI to get the .so file.

.mk file is written in the native code using the c /c++ snippet.

Now to compile using JNI , there are the two common ways:

1.**While working old ADT + SDK versions:**
You would require a linux environment to be configured on the windows configuration for running the JNI commands on shell. This environment can be achieved via various software available on net such as cygwin setup.

2.**If the ADT + SDK versions that you use are updated:**
Then there is a NDK pluggin available in ADT itself . So it easier to work on the ndk and native library.
 [For more details on NDK visit here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply but i  already have compiled .so file, only i want to use that file in my android application. While doing this, i am getting errors while trying to access native code.thanks.