# Error trying to loadLibrary for PDFTron Android

Tags: java, android, pdf, java-native-interface, pdftron

I am getting a strange error when trying to integrate with PDFTron i.e PDFNet Android SDK:

> UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load PDFNetC: findLibrary returned null. Expected armv7a, found cpu_info: abi: armeabi-v7a

I have already checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396898/how-to-use-existing-so-file-in-android-application/14578718).

Most likely the native library provided by PDFNet Android SDK is not included in my project correctly.
Inside the lib folder I the downloaded package, there are native libraries and java library that both need to be included to my project.

Created a folder called jniLibs in main folder and place all .so (with corresponding folder structure) inside the jniLibs folder, i.e.:

[image]

This will allow Android Studio to automatically recognize the native library path.

I also specified product flavor to filter which .so to use, such as:

```
productFlavors {
    armv7a {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
    arm {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi"
        }
    }
    x86 {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "x86"
        }
    }
    armv8 {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a"
        }
    }
    x86_64 {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "x86_64"
        }
    }
    fat {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }
    }
}
```

Then I specified the jniLibs directory inside build.gradle file of your project, i.e.:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        svg.srcDir 'src/main/svg'
    }
}
```

Comment: I used this library in my project. I copied libPDFNetC.so file in "jni/libs/armeabi" folder and in .mk file "include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libPDFNetC
# this libs path is relative to my jni files, so, src/main/jni/libs/libPrecompiledLib.a
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/armeabi/libPDFNetC.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)" wrote this. It works properly in my project.

Comment: @KushPatel can you post answer with proper explaination?

Comment: @MaňishYadav done. I think it should work

Comment: If you are using standard jniLib structure (i.e. jniLibs in main as shown in your first screenshot), you don't need to specify it in sourceSets anymore. The one in sourceSets is conflicting with the standard structure. See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topicsearchin/pdfnet-sdk/android$20AND$20author$3Asgong@pdftron.com/pdfnet-sdk/0t_3-pN5jG4

Answer (score 1):

Import PDFTron Library Project in Android Studio.
Use that Library Project in your application.For this use `compile project(':libraries:PDFViewCtrlTools')` in your application's `build.gradle`.

Now copy  `libPDFNetC.so` file to "jni/libs/armeabi" folder in your application.

in your `application.mk` write this.

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11 -exception
APP_STL := gnustl_shared
APP_PLATFORM=android-19
APP_OPTIM := debug
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8
```

in your `Android.mk` file add this

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libPDFNetC
# this libs path is relative to my jni files, so, src/main/jni/libs/libPrecompiledLib.a
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/armeabi/libPDFNetC.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Edit:

```
PDFDoc doc = PDFDoc(InputStream var1)
```

may be by using this method you can open PDF from url.

Code:

```
PDFViewCtrl mPDFViewCtrl = (PDFViewCtrl) view.findViewById(R.id.pdfViewer);
PDFDoc doc = new PDFDoc(filePath);
mPDFViewCtrl.setDoc(doc);
```

xml

```
<pdftron.PDF.PDFViewCtrl
    android:id="@+id/pdfViewer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Comment: You have to use this https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/mobile/request_trial.html. And PDFTron is a licensed product so you have to fill up those information.

Comment: @maven go to "samples" folder and check

Comment: I have navigated but there is no [Library Project in it.](http://i.imgur.com/p9kjlaV.png)

Comment: Go to this '\lib\src\PDFViewCtrlTools' path and you can also find PDFNet.jar file in 'lib' folder.

Comment: @maven yes. If in your manifest package ="com.pdftron.pdf.tools" then you are at right path.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using standard jniLib structure (i.e. jniLibs in main as shown in your first screenshot), you don't need to specify it in sourceSets anymore. `jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']` in sourceSets is conflicting with the standard structure (jniLibs).

See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topicsearchin/pdfnet-sdk/android$20AND$20author$3Asgong@pdftron.com/pdfnet-sdk/0t_3-pN5jG4